# Relative path is not working in soring-boot application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, relative-path

#I am working on windows machine. I have file under test folder and accessing it in application.yml file but it's not working.
FYI: Absolute path for the same is working.

application.yml
jwk-path: ..\test\resources\xyz.json

error:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\test\resources\xyz.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you run tests from IDE, it will try to load from the "root project". Can you try src/test/resources/xyz.json instead?

Comment: tried giving the path as: src/test/resources/xyz.json, but getting the same error Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\resources\xyz.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Sorry for the late reponse I never received the email for it.
How is your project organized?
Are you using Eclipse or Intellij?
Is the folder marked as test resources?